Polynomial Multiplication using Induction
I know there are easier ways to derive the formula (for example here), but I'd like to do it with induction:
The statement to prove is:
\begin{equation*}
\forall n,m \in \mathbb{N}_0 : \forall x \in \mathbb{R} : \qquad
\Big ( \sum^{n}_{k=0} a_k x^k \Big ) \Big ( \sum^{m}_{k=0} b_k x^k  \Big ) =  \sum^{n+m}_{k=0} \Big ( \sum^{k}_{l=0} a_l b_{k-l}  \Big ) x^k
\end{equation*}

Start: $n=0, \forall m \in \mathbb{N}_0 : \forall x \in \mathbb{R} :$
\begin{align*}
\Big ( \sum^{0}_{k=0} a_k x^k \Big ) \Big ( \sum^{m}_{k=0} b_k x^k  \Big ) &= a_0 \sum^{m}_{k=0} b_k x^k  \\ &= \sum^{m}_{k=0} (a_0 b_k + a_1 b_{k-1} + \cdots + a_k b_0) x^k \\ &=  \sum^{0+m}_{k=0} \Big ( \sum^{k}_{l=0} a_l b_{k-l}  \Big ) x^k
\end{align*}
Here I assumed that $0 = a_1 = a_2 = \cdots$

Step $n \implies n+1$
\begin{align*}
\Big ( \sum^{n+1}_{k=0} a_k x^k \Big ) \Big ( \sum^{m}_{k=0} b_k x^k  \Big ) &=  \Big (a_{n+1}x^{n+1} + \sum^{n}_{k=0} a_k x^k \Big ) \Big ( \sum^{m}_{k=0} b_k x^k  \Big ) \\ &=  a_{n+1}x^{n+1} \Big ( \sum^{m}_{k=0} b_k x^k  \Big ) + \sum^{n+m}_{k=0} \Big ( \sum^{k}_{l=0} a_l b_{k-l}  \Big ) x^k
\end{align*}
Now I'd only need to prove:
\begin{equation*}
\sum^{m}_{k=0} a_{n+1} b_k x^{k+n+1}  = \Big (\sum^{n+m+1}_{l=0} a_{l} b_{n+m+1-l} \Big )x^{n+m+1} 
\end{equation*}
Any ideas on how to proceed here?

The answer by acat3 exposes some of your difficulties. I think that inductive argument is made unnecessarily difficult because the bounds of the inner sum hide the constraints on the indices.  A better idea could be to try and prove that the product is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+m}\left(\sum_{\ell=\max{0,k-m}}^{\min{n,k}}a_\ell b_{k-\ell}\right)x^k.$$
One of the points is that this really is the same formula! For if $\ell<k-m$ then $k-\ell>m$ when $b_{k-\ell}=0$. Similarly, if $\ell>n$, then $a_\ell=0$. This way forces you to the key realization that the number of terms in the inner sum changes.

The Mistake
So for $n = 0$, you stated

Here I assumed that $0 = a_{1} = a_{2} = ...$

or in other words, $a_{k} = 0$ for all $k \geq n+1$.
In your second polynomial $b_{k} = 0$ for all $k \geq m+1$.
Thus,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{m}a_{n+1}b_{k} x^{k+n+1}
=
\sum_{l=0}^{n+m+1} a_{l}b_{n+m+1-l} x^{n+m+1}
$$
is none other than $0 = 0$. Your attempt is doomed from the beginning because you force the coefficients of the first polynomial to be zero, except the constant.
Therefore, whatever results you obtain from the algebraic manipulation is only valid if the first polynomial is a constant.
The Corrected Approach
You have proven the following for $n=0$:
$$
\forall l > n, \phantom{x} a_{l} = 0 \implies
\left(\sum_{p=0}^{n}a_{p}x^{p}\right)
\left(\sum_{q=0}^{m}b_{q}x^{q}\right)
=
\sum_{k=0}^{n+m}
\sum_{l=0}^{k}a_{l}b_{k-l}x^{k}
$$
Now this is the missing step. For any integer $n$ such that the above holds, we show that
$$
\forall l > n+1, \phantom{x} a_{l} = 0 \implies
\left(\sum_{p=0}^{n}a_{p}x^{p}\right)
\left(\sum_{q=0}^{m}b_{q}x^{q}\right)
=
\sum_{k=0}^{n+m}
\sum_{l=0}^{k}a_{l}b_{k-l}x^{k}
-
a_{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}b_{k}x^{k+n+1}
$$
Notice that the right-hand side changes because $a_{n+1}$ is no longer treated as zero.
This is why you cannot substitute the result from $n=0$ directly into the induction step.
Now substitute this instead to obtain the following:
$$
\left(
\sum_{p=0}^{n+1} a_{p}x^{p}
\right)
\left(
\sum_{q=0}^{m} b_{q}x^{q}
\right)
=
a_{n+1}b_{m} x^{n+m+1} +
\sum_{k=0}^{n+m}
\sum_{l=0}^{k}a_{l}b_{k-l}x^{k}
$$
It is quite trivial to see that
$$
a_{n+1}b_{m} x^{n+m+1}
=
\sum_{l=0}^{n+m+1} a_{l} b_{n+m+1-l} x^{n+m+1}
$$
because $a_{l} = 0$ for all $l > n+1$ while $b_{k} = 0$ for all $k > m$.
Then the proof is complete.

I thought the assumption was valid, because I meant that all coefficients higher than the degree of the polynomial are zero. Just like the polynomial $x^2+x+1$ has coefficients $0 = a_3 = a_4 = \cdots$. Without this I couldn't figure out how to make the start work. Should I use the constraint that $a_n \neq 0 \neq b_m$? How could I fix it?

I took that assumption to only apply to the base case when $n = 0$ so the left-hand polynomial is the constant $a_0$. That case is fine.

@haifisch123 I have added the correct approach to the answer

@SammyBlack that case is fine, until you perform a substitution. Remember that you can only substitute equivalent expression and those two expression are only equivalent when the first polynomial is a constant. So you cannot generalize to non-constant polynomials that way
